# npm update is broken, how do I fix this?

Tags: homebrew, node.js

I decided it was time to update my `node` and `npm` versions. I had these versions:

```
$ node -v
v6.9.4

$ npm -v
5.5.1
```

I ran a `brew upgrade node` because I am on a Mac, of course.

I got the following errors and suggestions to fix:

```
==> Pouring node-9.3.0_1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.3.0_1: 5,125 files, 49.6MB
danales-MacBook-Pro:Projects danale$ node -v
v6.9.4
danales-MacBook-Pro:Projects danale$ npm -v
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

When I attempted `brew postinstall node`, I got this error:

```
$ brew postinstall node
==> Postinstalling node
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/BROKEN.org
```

It appears to be a permission error, but I am unclear as to how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I completely removed `node` via `brew uninstall --force node` and then ran `brew install node`.

Afterwards, I ran `curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`

Reviewed both versions installed:

```
$ npm -v
5.6.0

$ node -v
v9.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who get here: I got this error when I tried to install node via homebrew when I already had a non-homebrew version installed. To fix this, I renamed the installed version:

```
mv /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node_orig
```

Then did the post-install step successfully:

```
brew postinstall node
brew link --overwrite node
```